# Laravel 4.2 Input File Null

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have form for upload multiple image file combine with Laravel 4.2 and Ajax. But when uploaded image, input file always NULL. How can i fix it ?

This my Upload Form.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('member.font.upload.images'), 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'upload-images', 'method'=> 'post')) }}
    {{ Form::file('image[]', array('multiple'=>true, 'id'=>'images')) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="font" value="{{ $font->id }}">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And Upload Process in Controller.

```
public function uploadImages()
{
$rules = array(
    'font' => 'required'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Response::json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed upload image']);
} else {
    if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        $images = Input::file('image');
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $imagename = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $upload =  $image->move('images/', $imagename);

            if($upload){
                $data = new Image;
                $data->font_id      = Input::get('font');
                $data->name         = $imagename;
                $data->save();
            }
        }
        return Response::json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Success']);
    }else{
        return Response::json(['success' => false, 'message' => 'File not found']);
    }
}
}
```

And then Ajax process.

```
$('#images').change(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: $('#upload-images').attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#upload-images').serialize(),
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $('.add-images').removeClass('enabled').addClass('uploading');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.add-images').removeClass('uploading').addClass('enabled');
    },
    error: function() {}
    });
});
```

Comment: using `serialize()` does not upload files. It's not hard to research how to upload files with ajax

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define encoding type of the form.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('member.font.upload.images'), 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'upload-images', 'method'=> 'post', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data")) }}
```

You can use this [W3Schools doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) to understand more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Change this section:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('member.font.upload.images'), 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'upload-images', 'method'=> 'post')) }}
```

> To:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'member.font.upload.images', 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'upload-images', 'method'=> 'post')) }}
```

Comment: This my route

    Route::post('upload-images', array('as'=>'member.font.upload.images', 'uses'=>'MemberController@uploadImages'));

Comment: doesn't resolve problem that no files are being uploaded in the first place

Comment: Maybe the problem is ur ajax $('#upload-images').serialize() try it to $('form').serialize(),